# UWP Application with ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession exploding memory usage when minimized

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I have a UWP Application which reads live Bluetooth data from a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device, plots it using [QuickCharts](https://github.com/ailon/UWPQuickCharts), and logs it to a csv file.

Currently every 250ms a Timer is triggered, which logs the data and updates the graph (this last operation is scheduled on the UI Thread).

I had a problem by which the application went into [suspended state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) whenever it was minimized or covered by another app, so I decided to enable the restricted capabilities in the App maifest and declared an `ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession` (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution)). This solved the issue, and the data is logged following the timer even when the app is minimized.

However, this caused the following effect: Whenever the App is minimized (not covered by another, but minimized), the memory usage explodes, and grows at around 100MB/min. My hypothesis is that although the app is in an active state, and the UI Tasks are scheduled, they are not able to run when the App is minimized. When I again maximize the App, the memory usage quickly drops and the graph updates quickly until it catches up. My question is the following:

1. Is it possible to run scheduled UI Tasks when the App is minimized?
2. If not, is it possible to detect when the App is minimized in order to not launch those tasks in that case? (but keeping the logging, which does work now through the Extended Session).

I am thankful for any insight, and apologize for my inexperience with UWP.

Comment: use memory profiler from Visual Studio to debug the usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it turned out that indeed the UI Tasks could not be fired if the App was minimized. To detect this, I subscribed to the `Window.Current.VisibilityChanged` event, which only gets triggered when the App is minimized and not when it looses focus, so I can therefore detect when this happens and only conditionally fire UI Update Tasks, while other tasks continue running, as the App is in a continued Foreground Execution Session.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run scheduled UI Tasks when the App is minimized?

When the application is minimized, the application enters the Suspend state. This is not done immediately, but the application is suspended after being minimized for a period of time.

In the suspend state, the current application state is retained until the next time the application is resumed or closed, during which the UI scheduled work cannot be performed

> If not, is it possible to detect when the App is minimized in order to not launch those tasks in that case?

Currently UWP does not provide an API to check whether the window is minimized, but the `Suspend` event will be triggered after minimizing, So we can handle the `App.OnSuspending`, you can turn off the functions when the event is triggered.

Specific content can view [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app)

Comment: It is my understanding, as explained in the last [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) I posted, that if I use an ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession the app will never go into suspended state. Is that not true? Because it in my opinion is very explicit in the documentation

Comment: Update: After testing as you suggested, the Suspending event never gets triggered, as expecetd. Something obviously changes in the App state, as the memory usage grows, but it is not suspension.

Comment: You might consider writing code that turns off related features in triggering code for extended execution.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. My problem here is to know which features exactly are not available in an extended execution session that are available when the app is actually in the foreground, as I can't find anything like that in the documentation

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. You mentioned in the question description that you need to not launch some tasks. The feature I mean is these tasks. I don't know what your task specifically refers to. But one thing is clear, at present UWP does not provide an API to detection minimize the window. So you can’t use window minimization as a basis for judgment.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But if I can't detect when the window is minimized, and the suspending event is not triggered (I can't change that as I need at least the logging tasks to run at all time), how can I detect when the app is in this state when (I am guessing) the UI tasks can't run?

Comment: If the application starts to perform extended execution, it means that the application is no longer in the foreground, and no UI-related operations should be performed at this time. If your extension executes the same method as in the foreground, you can pass in a parameter to identify whether the method is called in the foreground or by the extension and perform the appropriate processing

Comment: Well, I don't think it works like that. The request for the Extended Session is granted (I check that) before the App ever gets minimized, and after that I don't interact with that API in any way, so I can't know when I should stop triggering UI tasks. (Does this confirm that UI tasks can't be scheduled when the app is minimized, even if it is not suspended? Do you maybe have a source for that? Maybe I can find some more info there)

Comment: So you created `ExtendedExecutionSession` while the app was still in the foreground? The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution#run-while-minimized) gives two ways to create, one is in the foreground, the other is to trigger Suspending, I think according to your needs, you are suitable to create extended execution when Suspending is triggered.

Comment: Well, according to the document, if I request the extension only when I receive the Suspending event, I only gain some time to save the data before the suspended state is reached. This is not what I need, as the logging tasks need to work at all time. What I need is to know when the (insert name here) state is reached, where I can't fire UI tasks and disable those. Maybe some hack where I attempt to schedule something in the UI Thread immediately and check for success?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are hacking methods to achieve your purpose, but I didn't find relevant instructions for your needs.